# Basis for L_infty(R)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be the Banach space of bounded sequences of reals with the sup norm. Does there exists a subset $B$ of $V$ such that

- Linear Independence:  For all functions $c$ in $\mathbb{R}^B$, if $\sum_{b \in B} c(b) \cdot b = 0$, then $c$ is identically zero.
- Spanning Set:  For all vectors $v$ in $V$, there exists a function $c$ in $\mathbb{R}^B$ such that $\sum_{b \in B} c(b) \cdot b = v$.

If so, is an explicit such $B$ known?

Comment: he Banach space V with which you start would seem to be $\ell^\infty_{\mathbb R}$ and not $L^\infty({\mathbb R})$ -- as it happens, the two are (non-isometrically) isomorphic as Banach spaces, but this is not trivial and the isomorphism is slightly mysterious. Could you clarify whether you had one or the other in mind when you asked this question?

Comment: Why the set of $e_j=(0,\ldots,0,1,0\ldots)$ does not work ? 

Comment: Yemon, I had the sequence space in mind.  
Leandro, that's not a spanning set.

Comment: Are you requiring these functions to be zero for all but finitely many $b$? If so, this is just the statement that every vector space has a basis. I think you can't find an explicit basis.

Comment: No, and that's why I made my question more explicit than the topic.

Comment: Yemon, `$L^\infty(R)$` is isomorphic to `$\ell^\infty$`, not `$\ell^\infty_R$`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The space $\ell^\infty_R$ does not have even an M-basis; i.e., a biorthogonal set $(x_t,x_t^*)$ such that the span of the $x_t$ is dense and the $x_t^*$ are total (Lindenstrauss, late 1960s IIRC), so it has nothing like a Schauder basis. Later I proved [PAMS 26. no. 3 467-468 (1970)] that $\ell^\infty$ also does not have an M-basis.   However, each of these spaces does have a biorthogonal set $(x_t,x_t^*)$ such that the span of the $x_t$ is dense. This is in my paper with W.J. Davis [Studia Math. 45 173-179 (1973)].

Comment: What does "the $x_t^*$ are total" mean?

Comment: Separate points.

Answer (score 0):

It exists for any linear space (Banach structure is not essential here), is called Hamel base. No explicit construction (without use of Axiom of Choice) exists (and, I guess, it may proved in a sense - that existence of Hamel base in any linear space implies the axiom of choice or smth similar).

Comment: No, a Hamel base is what you would get if you required the cs to be zero for all but finitely many b.

Comment: If $c$ is not assumed to be finitely supported, then how do you understand this sum? Should it be absolutely convergent series in almost every point?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29#Abelian_topological_groups

Comment: So, $B$ is not countable, but $c$ is countably supported and the convergence is unconditional in $L_{\infty}$ norm. Right?

Comment: Ricky: could you please edit the question to clarify what notion of convergence (unconditional?) you had in mind -- the link you give to wikipedia is implicitly restricting its attention in many places to countably-indexed series and some extra precision would be welcome.

Comment: That is equivalent in the current $V$, although in more general (non-normable) spaces you could have the sum converge without $c$ being countably supported.

Comment: Yemon, where is it implicitly restricting its attention to countably-indexed series?

Comment: Ricky: regarding the Wikipedia page, my mistake. I still think the question might be a little clearer if you said explicitly that you were talking about unconditional convergemce of the "series" - especially to indicate that you are talking about something a little different from a Schauder basis