# Are coordinate functionals on complete vector spaces always continuous?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

(I'm just adding the completeness condition to $V$ from [this 2 month old question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42731/are-coordinate-functions-on-topological-vector-spaces-always-continuous), because I realized it's relevant to whether Bill Johnson's answer to [this 4 month old question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34967/basis-for-l-inftyr) actually answers the question.)

Let $V$ be a complete Hausdorff locally convex topological vector space over the field $\mathbb{K}$.

Let $B$ be a subset of $V$ such that

$\;$ for all functions $c : B\to \mathbb{K}$, if $\displaystyle\sum_{b\in B} \; c(b)\cdot b = \textbf{0}$, then $c$ is identically zero

and $f : B\times V \to \mathbb{K}$ be a function such that

$\;$ for all vectors $v$ in $V$, $\; \displaystyle\sum_{b\in B} \; f(b,v)\cdot b = v$.

Let $b$ be a member of $B$, and $g : V \to \mathbb{K}$ be given by $g(v) := f(b,v)$. Does it follow that $g$ is continuous?

Comment: The sums are unconditional, as explained at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29#Abelian_topological_groups.

Comment: For Banach (or Frechet) spaces the answer is "Yes", but I think you know that youself since you posted the question in such generality.

Comment: I didn't actually know that (and I still don't know a proof or reference, do you know one?), I was just more interested in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\ell_1:=\ell_1(\Bbb{N}\cup \{0\})$  as the dual of $c$, the space of convergent sequences indexed by $\Bbb{N}$, where the action is given by $e_0^*(x)=\lim_n x(n)$ and $e_n^*(x)=x(n)$ for $n\ge 1$. Put the bw$^*$ topology on $\ell_1$ under this pairing, which is the largest locally convex topology that agrees with the weak$^*$ topology on bounded sets.  IIRC, this is a complete topology (while the weak$^*$ topology is only boundedly complete). This is an unconditional basis that is not a Schauder basis because $e_n^*$ converges weak$^*$ to $e_0^*$.

Comment: Does the bw* topology have a more concrete description in this instance?  Also, what definition of Schauder basis are you using?

Comment: Schauder means all of the coordinate functionals are continuous.  I never thought much about the bw$^*$ topology, although I know some books on functional analysis do treat it.  If you only care about sequential completeness or that bounded Cauchy nets converge, use the weak$^*$ topology instead.

Comment: @Ricky:  Look at almost any book on Banach space theory.  It is the first theorem mentioned in Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri (without proof) and the first theorem mentioned in Albiac-Kalton (with proof).

Comment: @Ricky.  Regarding your query about a more concrete description of the topology in question, it is the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets.  This works for the dual of eny Banach space (even, in a suitable form, of a Frechet space).  It is even the finest topology with the above property (not just locally convex topology), a fact which is often useful.  This is all part of the circle of ideas surrounding the theorem of Banach-Dieudonne.